# Dynamically created form is not submitting

Tags: jquery

I have a set of forms which is dynamically created.

```
<form action='test.php' method='post' name='addtocart' id='form1'>
<input class="qty" type="text" size="3" name="quantity" value="1">
<input class="btnStandard" type="button" name="submit" value="Add to Cart">
</form>
<form action='test.php' method='post' name='addtocart' id='form2'>
<input class="qty" type="text" size="3" name="quantity" value="1">
<input class="btnStandard" type="button" name="submit" value="Add to Cart">
</form>
```

By clicking the button with class `btnStandard` the corresponding form will get submit.
My jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.btnStandard', function(event){
            var formId = $(this).parent("form[name='addtocart']").attr('id');
            alert(formId);  //gives the form id
            $('form#'+formId).submit(); 
    });
});
```

But the form is not submitting.

**EDIT**

I missed it:
I edited the Question as suggested in comment. Still the form is not get submit, but the alert is working.

Comment: Change: `$(".btnStandard").on('click', function(event){` to `$(document).on('click', ".btnStandard", function(event){`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: @Stuart, I tried but not worked. I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

There's two main issues here. Firstly if the `form` elements are dynamically created you will need to use a delegated event handler.

Secondly, to submit a form it has to have a `submit` button, so change the `type` on the `input type="button"` elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.btnStandard', function(event) {
    var formId = $(this).parent("form[name='addtocart']").attr('id');
    alert(formId); //gives the form id
    $('form#' + formId).submit();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action='test.php' method='post' name='addtocart' id='form1'>
  <input class="qty" type="text" size="3" name="quantity" value="1">
  <input class="btnStandard" type="submit" name="submit" value="Add to Cart">
</form>

<form action='test.php' method='post' name='addtocart' id='form2'>
  <input class="qty" type="text" size="3" name="quantity" value="1">
  <input class="btnStandard" type="submit" name="submit" value="Add to Cart">
</form>
```

However, with that said retrieving the DOM element to get an `id` from it to select it again by that `id` is entirely redundant. Just use `closest()` to get the form and remove the `name` and `id` from them:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.btnStandard', function(event) {
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="test.php" method="post">
  <input class="qty" type="text" size="3" name="quantity" value="1">
  <input class="btnStandard" type="submit" name="submit" value="Add to Cart">
</form>

<form action="test.php" method="post">
  <input class="qty" type="text" size="3" name="quantity" value="1">
  <input class="btnStandard" type="submit" name="submit" value="Add to Cart">
</form>
```

Comment: In which case you must have another underlying issue as you can see from the above example. Try checking the console for errors